# Morphism from blow up to a linear projection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $L$ be a linear subspace of $P^n$ defined by say $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_m=0$. Consider the projection of $P^n$ to $P^m$ from $L$. This is a rational map $f:P^n\rightarrow P^m$ defined on the complement of $L$ by $(x_0:\cdots:x_n)\mapsto (x_0:\cdots:x_m)$.

Let $P'$ be the blow up of $P^n$ along L and consider $f':P'\rightarrow P^m$. I am trying to understand this morphism.

Edit:
Let $p:P'\rightarrow P^n$ the blow up morphism. Then what is the direct image of the line bundles $p^*O(i)$ under $f'$. I would in particular like to know what is $f'_*O_{P'}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{O}_{P'}(i)$?

Comment: For $\mathcal{O}_{P'}(i)$ cf. Hartshorne, "Algebraic geometry", pp. 117, 161, 163.

Comment: @ThomasPreu: it is better to give an actual explanation instead of a reference to Hartshorne.

Comment: The Picard group of the variety $P'$ has rank 2, so there are more than one choice of an ample line bundle, and therefore the notation $\mathcal{O}_{P'}(1)$ is ambiguous. Consequently, the answer to your question depends on the choice of this line bundle.

Comment: @Sasha. I am sorry. If $p:P'\rightarrow P^n$ is the blow up morphism, then I denoted $p^*O(i)$ by $O_{P'}(i)$. I would in particular like to know what is $f'_*O_{P'}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The morphism $f' \colon P' \to \mathbb{P}^m$ is a projective bundle; more precisely
$$
P' \cong \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^m}(\mathcal{O}^{\oplus (n-m)} \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)).,$$
hence $f'_*\mathcal{O}_{P'} \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^m}$. Moreover, $\mathcal{O}_{P'}(1)$ is the relative hyperplane bundle for this projective bundle, therefore if $i > 0$ then
$$
f'_*\mathcal{O}_{P'}(i) \cong \mathrm{Sym}^i(\mathcal{O}^{\oplus (n-m)} \oplus \mathcal{O}(1)).
$$

Comment: thank you! Here are you still using the notation $O_{P'}(1) =p^*O_{P^n}(1)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I am using your notation.